# mongoose express node.js javascript function return undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

```
function getPassword(uname)
{

    User.findOne({'username': uname},{'password': 1}, function(err, cb)
    {
        console.log("print 2");
        return cb.password;
    });
    console.log("print 1");
}
```

I'm new to node.js. Currently, I have this function when called should return the password from mongodb. However, whenever I debug, I realised that "print 1" is always printed before "print 2" and the app.post function that calls this method and store to a variable always return "undefined".

Appreciate if anyone can explain to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because "print 2" occurs inside the callback. When findOne finishes it then fires the callback function.

Basically the main event loop in node fires `User.findOne` and then immediately moves on to "print 1". Then a bit later `findOne` finishes and fires the callback function you supplied, which then fires "print 2".

Comment: Thanks! I think I get what you mean.

Comment: Np. Don't forget to give me the green check mark if I answered your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

@Alex Ford is right. In Node.js there should not be blocking approach. Instead use callbacks for mostly everything :)

So your `getPassword()` helper just need one more argument `callback [Function]` which will be called after job is done.

```js
function getPassword(uname, cb) {
  User.findOne({'username': uname}, {'password': 1}, cb(err, data));
}

app.post('/somewhere', function (req, res, next) {
  // ...
  getPassword(username, function (err, password) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    console.log("I got '%s' password!", password);
  });
});
```

tl;dr
Just follow nested callbacks and that'd be fine. In general think in *async* way not *sync* :)

Code above isn't tested so please first test it ;)